# MongoDB Concurrency Issue

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, locking, nosql

I have a scenario for my app which is similar to sending friend request in Facebook.

When user A sends friend request to user B, internally a new friend request document is created. At a later time when user B also wants to send friend request to A, system would find out that a friend request document existed and so they should be friend of each other, no new friend request document would be created.

I'm trying to figure out the case when user A and user B both simultaneously sends friend request to each other which will then create 2 friend request documents and leading to undetermined behaviour...

Thanks for your suggestions.. Really appreciated!

Edit:
A few had suggested to use a request queue to solve this; however,
I'm confused about using queue because i thought it would make my rest api endpoint process requests sequentially. Wouldn't I lose all the benefit of multi-threading by using queue? I can't help but imagine how bad it would be if my service has millions of requests queued and waiting to be executed one by one just due to this issue. Has anyone seen something along similar problems seen in production?

Answer (score 4):

I had similar situation with my client which has concurrent writes in the database, What I have implemented is a Queue service.

```
Create a request in the queue rather than writing in the database, a separate reader will 
read one message from the queue at a time and check if it is valid to write it to 
database, write only if there is no previous request.
```

You can implement your own queue or you can use service like AWS-SQS, rabbitmq, MSMQ etc.

Comment: Doesn't that mean my server won't process requests in parallel anymore, which means it will not be as performant as before?

Comment: No, only this particular functionality's write operation will go through a queue. You can have parallel readers if you want

Comment: yes, but if there's a load of write operations queued, wouldn't the response be very slow or even timeout eventually? I mean is it worth it to tradeoff performance over this rare case? I'm hoping there's other way to resolve this kind of very rare case.. :(

Comment: Yes, it seems like a corner case, but I doubt about slow response. Not sure if there is another way, Plz share your implementation if you figure out the problem in some other way :)

Comment: Why bother having a single item for A->B and B->A. AFAIK, i'd live with those two items, unless having only one is strictly necessary. What's the use case of such a composite object ? Otherwise, you could opt for a mixin between what was suggested previously (a queue), and a kind of sharding (meaning you have several queues, so that you still can use parallelism). You could set-up 8 queues, for 8 each users groups (groupes by id modulus for example).

Comment: @SCO the use case is like the friend request example I put in my question. If it creates 2 items A->B and B->A the problem is that instead of converting them to friends of each other, it creates friend request that can be visible to both party, which is pretty much undetermined.. To use multiple queues, wouldn't it still be possible for these 2 requests to be processed simultaneously?

Comment: @user1955934 No need to have multiple queue, single queue will solve the problem

Comment: I'm confused about using queue because i thought it would make my rest api endpoint process request sequentially; which I could achieve using synchronized block ... can anyone explain how queue is better than just using synchronized block?

Comment: @user1955934 A "synchronized block" is a queue with 0 length.  There are advantages to using a queue like guaranteed delivery, buffering.... you are overthinking this, the solution is a Queue or event log... .

Comment: @Kickaha, im not saying that synchronized block is the solution and using queue would definitely solve this issue, but I can't accept it as it doesn't scale for my purpose. Using multiple workers to process requests in the queue would still have the same issue. I need a solution where requests can still be processed in parallel without an issue. It's like I'm asking how do I solve multi-threaded issue and suggested to use single-thread as a solution.. :(

Comment: @user1955934, the race condition problem you have can only be solved by processing items one by one.  That's a logical boundary you are stuck with unless you are using quantum entangled Q bits.  The benefits you gain from asynchronous communications do not transfer into your procedural logic, but you can keep the most significant benefit (non blocking communication between clients' and service) by pooling the requests in a queue or event log so that processing is guaranteed.  For any parallelism benefits I'd concentrate on coding the daemon that processes that log / event queue.

Answer (score 4):

// Specific to your case

1. In mongodb write operations on a single document are atomic.
2. mongodb has a feature of unique index.

Hence if you insert the document with an _id(or any other unique index) with person names A and B by creating unique index for both (such as "A_B" by lexicographically sorting the names) before doing insertion. You will inherently be able to insert only one instance of that document.

// General

What essentially we would like to have are transactions but since mongodb doesn't support such, as of now. There are a few tricks to achieve this:

1. 2 phase commits : 
   https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/
2. Using an external source to maintain a flag, for example using memcache which supports insertion in transactional manner/Compare and Swap.

Comment: friend request has direction i.e. to mark which user sent request and which user it is targetted to. so it cannot be a document that can only be represented as A_B but rather A_B and B_A . And this is not a transaction/atomicity issue as the main issue is knowing what document to create based on a condition that may unexpectedly change; in this case, condition is "does friend request exist?", but this condition may not hold true anymore after the check is done...

Comment: To take care of direction , there can always be another field i.e. requestFrom, requestTo. Unique index should be an altogether different field, to mark the relation between A and B (which is unique and only once between A & B).

Comment: Adding to above comment, let me explain why i think this is a transaction issue: 
As u mentioned, "main issue is knowing what document to create based on a condition", this is a very simple problem which can be solved by a simple check in ur code, BUT "this condition may not hold true anymore after the check is done" the reason this condition will change is that there is no way to know if while reading there is another thread that may be writing, this problem could be solved if somehow u could acquire a read/write lock on the document. This is essentially transaction.

Comment: Having said this, the solution i suggested is not based on transaction, but a property (unique index) based on mongodb, which is effectively simpler, without the use of external queue or external flags. You would only have to handle 'duplicate id' exception that may arise on later commit.

Comment: I do have requestFrom and requestTo field in my friendRequest object. But this can't be unique since requestFrom A and requestTo B is not the same as requestFrom B and requestTo A. How should I create the unique index field if reqFrom and reqTo fields are different? And I think this isn't a transaction issue since by definition transaction is how we should do things in an atomic way, ie. 2 write ops and if one write failed, then both will fail. In this case i'm only doing an insert, based on a read operation...

Comment: Consider trying to insert the following 2 documents in ur table :

// User1 : A, User2 : B
// Req from A to B
db.friendReqTable.insert({_id:"A_B", reFrom:"A", reqTo:"B"});
// Req from B to A
db.friendReqTable.insert({_id:"A_B", reFrom:"B", reqTo:"A"});

you will find that, while inserting the second document you will get an error.

Comment: + to create unique index column other than _id;
use db.friendReqTable.createIndex( { "UIndex": 1 }, { unique: true } )

Comment: Right, but wouldn't the app do : db.friendReqTable.insert({_id:"B_A", reFrom:"B", reqTo:"A"}); for the second rquest? Like there's nothing that tells it to create A_B instead of B_A

Comment: thats where u can sort A,B before making the id as "A_B". So weather its 
A->B or B ->A it'll always come out as "A_B"

Answer (score 1):

Here if you use **system calls** method in frontend then you should fire one request to frontend from Database when some user like, I send you request then within a sec database send you one system call and your frontend code immediate correct the button text like

> "Add a friend" to "incoming request"

or else.

if you are only setting up database then just **make a system call** which send it to UI when friend request arrives or as you say Document created, the further process will be handled by UI Developer.
Thank you.
if you don't like the answer then I m apologize for that but don't downvote me because I M new in Stack Overflow Community.